# iOS Container View doesn't honour intrinsicContentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uistoryboard, autolayout

I want to use a Container View to contain a camera preview. I want the camera to centered in the middle and maintain it's proper aspect ratio. (it's pink to make it obvious where its frame is)

[image: Story board showing container view]

I'm stuck on the first step of trying to get the camera preview to appear at a size that's smaller than the container.

I have a UIView subclass for the Camera Controller's view, and have the code:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
  return CGSizeMake(320, 240);
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't honoured:

[image: iPad simulator result]

From reading the docs, `intrinsicContentSize` looks like it's what I want. Eventually I want to use Auto Layout as well, but I'm trying to solve one thing at a time.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Auto layout uses the `intrinsicContentSize` property.  If you're not using auto layout, the system will not ask any view for its `intrinsicContentSize`.

The pink view will be forced to the size of the container view unless you write some code.  This is true whether you are using auto layout or not.  This is just the way container views created in a storyboard work.  The system will not ask your pink view for its `intrinsicContentSize`.

Since you imply that you're *not* using auto layout, here's one way you can make the container view be the `intrinsicContentSize` of its content view.  Make a subclass of `UIView` called `CameraContainerView` and set this as the custom class of the container view.  Override `addSubview:` in this new class:

```
@implementation CameraContainerView

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)subview {
    [super addSubview:subview];
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size = subview.intrinsicContentSize;
    self.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

That is sufficient in my testing.  (It won't stay up to date if the subview changes its `intrinsicContentSize` dynamically.)

If you decide to use auto layout, you need to set up constraints between the container view and the content view, and you need to remove any conflicting constraints.

First, in your storyboard, make sure the container view has explicit width and height constraints. (These constraints will be deleted so their exact sizes don't matter.)  Give `CameraContainerView` an outlet for each of these constraints:

```
@interface CameraContainerView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

@end
```

Connect these outlets to the constraints in the storyboard. Note that these outlets are on `CameraContainerView`, **not** on `ViewController`, so don't try to control-drag from the view controller to the constraints; that won't work.

Also make sure that the container view isn't pinned to both the left and right (leading and trailing) edges of its superview, and that it isn't pinned to both the top and bottom of its superview.  It's important that the container view's size be determined only by its explicit width and height constraints.

After you've set up the constraints in the storyboard and hooked up the outlets, you can rewrite `addSubview:` for auto layout.  You'll need to turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the embedded view:

```
@implementation CameraContainerView

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)subview {
    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [super addSubview:subview];
```

Then you need to remove the width and height constraints that were loaded from the storyboard:

```
    [self removeConstraint:self.widthConstraint];
    self.widthConstraint = nil;
    [self removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
    self.heightConstraint = nil;
```

Finally you can set up new constraints that position the embedded view in the container view and make the container view match the size of the embedded view:

```
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview);
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
        constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subview]|"
        options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
        constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subview]|"
        options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}

@end
```

That worked in my testing, and should stay up to date if the subview changes its `intrinsicContentSize` dynamically, as long as the subview sends itself `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`.

Comment: Thanks for this, your examples and explanation are really helpful and  I have a better grasp on how it works now. Unfortunately the default behaviour for Container Views in the storyboard seem to be a black box.

Comment: surely explicitly setting frame.size = subview.intrinsicContentSize is cheating, not to mention mixing frames and Auto Layout. Better to set the size constraints using the subview.intrinsicContentSize values. To be honest, I'm struggling to understand why the Auto Layout runtime doesn't automatically invoke - (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize, when it's overridden in a UIView.

Comment: “explicitly setting frame.size = subview.intrinsicContentSize” is not “cheating”.  I did that in the scenario where **the app is not using auto layout**.  Read my answer: “Since you imply that you're *not* using auto layout, …”

Comment: Am I correct when I say that even if a view (`viewA`) has subviews with constraints that could define `viewA`'s width, that `viewA` still does not have an intrinsic content size, and that it doesn't adjust its width and its height based on the subviews' width and height?

Comment: @Scott I don't understand what question has to do with bradley.ayers's original question.  Perhaps you should post a new top-level question.

Comment: My previous question was somewhat related to this. What I noticed is that the class of the top-level embedded view (**not** the container view) also needs to be subclassed and has to override `intrinsicContentSize` to a meaningful value. bradley.ayers already did that, but not doing it isn't an option. I can now answer my previous question: no, `intrinsincContentSize` does not have a meaningful value even if I let its size be determined by its subviews. However, simply overriding `intrinsicContentSize` to `return self.bounds.size` did solve that problem. Thanks again for your write-up, rob!

Comment: How to convert `    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview);` in swift?

Comment: This is the kind of scary stuff you find in the world when freelancing. You thought addSubview was just adding a subview...oh no my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I found bug in Interface Builder. With its help , you can add custom view with intrinsicContentSize.

1) Add UIButton on View in Interface Builder. I set centerY and centerX constraints. This button is your custom view. 
[image]

2) Replacement superclass your custom view to UIButton:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
@end
```

to

```
@interface CustomView : UIButton
@end
```

3) Set class UIButton in storyboard :

[image]

4) Return superclass your custom view:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
@end
```

5) Run. My CustomView show gray square (300х300) on center screen. Compiling without errors and warnings.

```
@implementation CustomView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(300, 300);
}

@end
```

**Result :**

[image]