# What causes Container View to keep its child view's frame to match its bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how Container Views work in the storyboard. The behaviour appears to be that the container view will force its subview to resize to fill the container.

[image: storyboard relationships]

I see no constraints that explain it, and there's no mention of what class it is. It seems like some storyboard magic.

[image: constraints]

I assume that the container view must be a subclass of `UIView`, and I'll have a wild guess and assume its called `UIContainerView`, but searching through the documentation yields only two results.

[image: search results]

So how does it work?

Comment: I don't think it is a subclass, I think it's just a UIView, and behind the scenes, Xcode sets the frame of the embedded controller to be equal to the bounds of the container view.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The storyboard editor (Interface Builder) keeps the embedded view's `frame` set to the container view's `bounds` during editing.  Thus when the storyboard is written to a file, the serialized sizes of the views are identical.  This happens whether or not the storyboard has auto layout enabled.

The top-level view of each view controller in the storyboard also has its autoresizing mask set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`, again regardless of whether the storyboard has auto layout enabled.

If auto layout is enabled, each top-level view has its `translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` set to `YES`.  This is different than all of the descendants of those top-level views.  All of the descendants have `translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` set to `NO`.

The embedding relationship is represented as a segue of class `UIStoryboardEmbedSegue`.  (This is a private class, not part of the public API.)

When `UIStoryboardEmbedSegue` receives the `perform` message, it loads the destination view controller's view and adds it as a subview of the container view.  Then it sets the embedded view's `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.  This is redundant, since Interface Builder already set it that way in the storyboard.

Then `-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegue perform]` checks the embedded view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints`.  This is also redundant, because Interface Builder set it to `YES`.

If the embedded view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` is `YES`, `perform` sets the embedded view's `frame` to the container view's `bounds`.  Again, redundant.

If the embedded view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` is `NO`, `perform` adds constraints `H:|[childView]|` and `V:|[childView]|`, thus forcing the embedded view to fill the container view.  (Yes, it actually uses the visual format language.)  This branch should not be reached.

When a view has `translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` set to `YES`, auto layout automatically adds constraints of type `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` and keeps them up to date when you change the view's `frame`.  For example, the root view of a window is made to fill the window using autoresizing constraints:

```
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7555d00 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x7671780.midX == UIWindow:0x7551010.midX>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7555de0 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x7671780.width == UIWindow:0x7551010.width>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7555eb0 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x7671780.midY == UIWindow:0x7551010.midY + 10>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7555ef0 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x7671780.height == UIWindow:0x7551010.height - 20>
```

So that's what “causes Container View to keep its child view's frame to match its bounds”.

I figured this out by looking at the `.storyboard` file (it's surprisingly readable XML), and by looking at `-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegue perform]` in [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/).

As for why they have the redundant checks, I can think of a few likely reasons:

1. IB (perhaps in pre-release versions) didn't always set up the view properties the way it does now, so the code isn't redundant when loading old storyboards.
2. Apple has internal tools that generate storyboards differently than IB.
3. The code is there for forward compatibility with future versions of IB that allow top-level storyboard views to have different properties.

Comment: Great explanation! Does that also mean that, when using a storyboard, it is not possible to have the contents of a container view decide the height of the container view (which has constraints applied centering the view in the view it's embedded in)?

Comment: @Scott It sounds like you should read my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17376240/77567).

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a test project and stepping through the code gives you a fairly clear idea of how this is implemented. The container view itself is a plain UIView. As part of the controllers loadView process, the container view is created with the constraints setup in the storyboard. The embedded controller segue is then performed. This creates the child view controller, which has its view added as a subview of the container view, and appropriate layout constraints setup so that the child view fills the container. Thats about it really.

Comment: Yes but obviously it's not working. After resising a ContainerView, the child views don't fit the new bound.