# convert objc to swift regarding NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/a/17376619/433570

Especially.

```
UIView* subview = ...;

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview);
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subview]|"
    options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

I've seen [NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings swift equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085140/nsdictionaryofvariablebindings-swift-equivalent)

But it didn't help me much, how can I translate the objc to swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just take every view that is listed in `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` and create a usual swift dictionary containing this view with the variable name as a key.

Example:

```
NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2, view3)
```

will become

```
["view1" : view1, "view2" : view2, "view3" : view3]
```

So

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview);
```

will become

```
let views = ["subview" : subview]
```

Comment: so, ["subview": subview] is it?

Comment: @eugene, yes, it's that simple. `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` just takes everything that is passed into it, and creates a dictionary like this at compile time (it is a macro).

Comment: @FreeNickname: it's part compile-time and part runtime. `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2, view3)` actually expands into `_NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(@"view1, view2, view3", view1, view2, view3, nil)` where `_NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` is a runtime API in Cocoa that actually creates the dictionary.